# Call my function instead anonymous function

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

I have a anonymous function that is running in `onconnect` event.
How to call my function `OnConnect()` instead anonymous function ?

```
$this->server->on("connect", function (WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
            $this->Logger->notice((" Connected " . $user->getIp()));
        });
```

And

```
public function OnConnect(WebSocketTransportInterface $user) {
    $this->Logger->notice((" Connected " . $user->getIp()));     
}
```

Something like

```
 $this->server->on("connect", OnConnect($user));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this

```
$this->server->on("connect", 'OnConnect');
```

and if this is in same class, do this:

```
$this->server->on("connect", array($this, 'OnConnect'));
```